# Why ajax requests are not getting cached/

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, caching

I am trying to use the cache feature of ajax. But it is not working in my requests. I want to cache all my requests. Here is my code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {
    call_ajax(); 
}); 
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    call_ajax(); 
});
function call_ajax(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "get",
        cache  : true,
        data: {offset : 3}, 
        dataType : "html",
        url: 'http://localhost/contents.php', 
        success: function(returnData){
            jQuery('.ajaxcontents').append(returnData);
        },
    }); 
}   
</script>
<div id="ajaxcontents"></div>
```

In file contents.php, I am setting the headers as follows.

```
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', strtotime("+5 days")), true);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: public");
```

When I check the request details on google inspect tool (under network tab) it always shows 200 for the first time and after that, when i scroll it shows 200 (from cache). Why is it not showing 200 (from cache) for first time, even after I reload the same page?

Comment: @HeroFTime : its not similar. Because my expire headers are always in future.

Comment: When you reload the page, are you sure you aren't doing a cache reload too? Are any of your assets being returned from cache?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `cache` to `true` in jQuery, it is true by default (except for `script` and `jsonp` data types).  Also, that parameter is only used to prevent caching by appending a timestamp URL parameter to your URL for HTTP GET requests only, otherwise the caching will assume the browser's default behaviour.

> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with
>   HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
>   GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of
>   requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already
>   been requested by a GET.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax1

Try adding a `max-age` in your `cache-control` header and and accompanying `If-Modified-Since`